# how to recover cascade classifier training from a stage?

Tags: opencv, cascade-classifier

i train cascade classifier in 20k positive and negative samples but after 1 day because power outage, turn off my pc. now i want know there is way to recover my training from stage 3 or must began from first ?

when i see `(-data D:/Data/)` Data folder several files exist like : `params, stage0 , ...` there is way to recover training from this files?

Comment: just start again with same parameters and folder names. It will print "loaded stage 0 to 2" or sth. in the beginning. You've used opencv_traincascade, right?

Comment: yes i  used opencv_traincascade. same parameters work, thanks.